# Trouble with getting an index of an array in java

Tags: java, arrays, bufferedreader

I have used a BufferedReader to read in information from a txt file. I know the file is reading but I cannot select the first index (bookID number) to go through my if statement. **I want the first line of the string to match with the bookID and then complete the if statements without skipping to the book is not found statement.** Code below.

```
 String bookID =  jTextField7.getText();
    String quantity = jTextField8.getText();


    jLabel9.setText("Item #" + Integer.toString(currItem) + "info");

    jButton8.setEnabled(false);
    jButton9.setEnabled(true);

    BufferedReader br = null;
    String sCurrentLine;

    try {

        //String sCurrentLine;
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("inventory.txt"));


        while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {

          String[] split = sCurrentLine.split(",");
          System.out.println(sCurrentLine);

                if (split[0] == bookID) {
                    int discount = calculateDiscount(Integer.parseInt(quantity));
                    double itemSubTotal = (Integer.parseInt(quantity)*new BigDecimal(split[2]).doubleValue()*(discount/100));
                    subTotal += itemSubTotal; 
                    String info = split[0] + " " +  split[1] + " " + split[2] + " " + quantity + " " + Integer.toString(discount) + " " + (Integer.parseInt(quantity)*new BigDecimal(split[2]).doubleValue()*(discount/100));
                    books.add(info);
                    jTextField9.setText(info);
                        return;
                }
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e ){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        try {
            if (br != null)br.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Book ID " + bookID + " not in File"); 

}
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: What is the content of `inventory.txt`?

Comment: 11111, "Top Secret Twenty One - Janet Evanovich", 8.99
22222, "W Is For Wasted - Sue Grafton", 9.95
33333, "Gray Mountain - John Grisham", 14.95
44444, "Revival - Stephen King", 12.95
55555, "Everyday Italian - Giada de Laurentiis", 18.99
66666, "Refusal - Felix Francis", 7.99
77777, "Dust - Patricia Cornwell", 12.99
88888, "Terminal City - Linda Fairstein", 10.95
99999, "Rogue Lawyer - John Grisham", 15.95
11112, "The Guilty - David Baldacci", 14.95
  @shmosel,  it's bookID, book, author, price

Answer (score 2):

To compare strings you need to use equals:

```
split[0].equals(bookId)
```

Comment: I made the change and I still received the same result.